# Firefox address bar and page are blank when running RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec-rails

I am getting this error

```
   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
   unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
```

Here is the list of my tests gems

```
capybara (2.1.0)
rspec (2.14.1)
rspec-core (2.14.3)
rspec-expectations (2.14.0)
rspec-mocks (2.14.1)
rspec-rails (2.14.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
```

My Firefox version is 29

When I downgraded my FF, it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and this works for me with Firefox version 28

In your Gemfile, replace the current version with

```
gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 2.38.0"
```

Then run,

```
gem update selenium-webdriver

bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 29 is not a stable release, it is still in *beta* - you *cannot*, **under any circumstances**, expect the team to support beta browser versions.

The answer lies within "When I downgrade my FF it works fine".

Selenium bundles the driver required for Firefox, it's actually a Firefox extension and requires maintenance & fixes to be kept up to date & stable with Firefox as it upgrades and steams through versions.

The solution is *usually* two-fold. The first one is remember that Selenium will only support certain versions of Firefox. When a new version of Firefox is released, there may be some compataibility issues, but usually, the team can get out a release quite quickly so you shouldn't be stuck for too long. This doesn't apply at all here, because you are using a beta version of a browser, something that any reasonable developer isn't going to do.

The Selenium team aim to support the latest version of Firefox, the previous version to that, the latest ESR (Extended Support) release and the previous version to that.

The second part of your solution is to keep Selenium [updated](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) all the time. Your version is months old regardless of your Firefox version & Selenium's support schedule.

You can see from the latest [change log](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG) that the support currently stands at:

```
17 (immediately previous ESR release)
24 (current ESR release)
27 (immediately previous release
28 (current release)
```

You are rolling back to a previous version, one that Selenium *actually* supports, that's why your problem is being fixed.

Comment: Latest firefox usually contains security fixes and it's important to be supported by selenium immediately. But I guess the reality is that resources of project are limited so what you say makes sense.

Comment: @akostadinov not true. Firefox 29 has been released since my answer here which now supports more HTML5 elements, such as `input` elements with a type of `number`. Up until now Firefox didn't support them and rendered them as generic normal input elements, and now it renders them properly. The FirefoxDriver needs updating to support it. That is one, of several hundreds, of examples about how Selenium & Firefox incompatibilities can happen.

Comment: I guess there is some misunderstanding because I don't think our comments contradict.

Comment: @akostadinov the statement "Firefox updates usually contains security fixes" simply isn't true. That's the point.

Comment: I said they usually contain and it is recommended for users to upgrade (hence for developers to test with the new versions). I didn't say it only contains such fixes if this is what you read. Here is a proof: https://www.mozilla.org/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox.html